# presentViewController black screen or thread debug in IDE

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have seen the abundance of threads on this issue - I have tried all those solutions and they have failed. The build that ran, when I click the button it goes to the thread debugger page and I have no clue as to whats going on.

I need to go from a new class with its own .xib to the MainStoryboard where FirstViewController is.

```
- (IBAction)backToHome:(id)sender {
    /*
    FirstViewController *fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:fvc animated:YES completion:nil];
     */
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    FirstViewController *fvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:fvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When using the commented code it goes to a black screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FirstViewController *fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:fvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Here **initWithNibName:nil** causes black screen as it is not able to load nib.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. So `initWithNibName` should be set to `@"MainStoryboard"` ? This brings me back into the IDE in the thread debug page

Comment: Do you have separate xib for FirstViewController or it is within storyboard ?

Comment: It is within the storyboard, it is Tab Bar Controller view 1

Comment: Then the second way of initializing FirstViewController with its Identifier is correct. That will work.

Comment: When I click the button the IDE opens on the thread debugger page and exits the app, does this make sense?

Comment: Have you set "FirstViewController" identifier in .storyboard ?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should add name

FirstViewController *fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"somethinghere" bundle:nil]; [self presentViewController:fvc animated:YES completion:nil];